# Holding the max and min peak from an sensor until the next max and min peak come (top and buttom of wave signal)

Tags: c++

I have a wave signal with an maximum and an minimum value in each waves. After the min value of the wave is come it should safe the min peak, an at the top the same, until the next min and max peake came. How can i handle it in c++ ?

Maybe with somethin like this?

```
# include <Wire.h>
#include <DFRobot_MAX30102.h>


DFRobot_MAX30102  particleSensor;
int               savedRed;
bool              increase;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Initialize sensor
  if (particleSensor.begin() == false) {
    Serial.println("MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power. ");
    while (1);
  }
  particleSensor.sensorConfiguration(0x1F,SAMPLEAVG_4,MODE_MULTILED,SAMPLERATE_400, PULSEWIDTH_411,ADCRANGE_4096);
  savedRed = particleSensor.getRed();
  increase = true;
}
 

void loop() {

  int red = particleSensor.getRed();

  red = particleSensor.getRed();
  if (increasing) {}
    if (red<savedRed) {
      Serial.print(savedRed);
      increasing = false;
    }
  } else if if (red>savedRed) {
    Serial.print(savedRed);
    increasing = true;
  }
  savedRed = red;
}
```

my try, but doesn't work was: https://pastebin.com/raw/CYQXDKhs

or maybe with a state machine with wait for a local minimum?

I have tryed if/else loops but one try doesn't clean the last peak until the next peak was lower, and the oder does not safe the peaks.

Comment: You should post the code here, not at a link that can go away at any time.

Comment: no statemachine needed, you just need `if (current < min) min = current;` and same for the max.

Comment: btw I have the feeling that `if (current < min) min = current;` is not really what you need, but you need to try to explain what more you need (and show a [mcve] of the code you wrote)

Comment: Why are you reading `red` twice?

Comment: There are both `increase` and `increasing` – typo? Use consistent variable names.

Comment: What makes you sure that the wave starts increasingly? If it actually doesn't you get a false positive right at the beginning. I personally would use some kind of tri-state (unknown, increasing, decreasing) – and remain in unknown as long as initial direction hasn't yet been determined. That would cover a constant signal (error situation) as well.

Comment: " if (current < min) min = current;" But if the next min peak is higher then the last one, i doesn't get him.

Comment: `else if if (red>savedRed)` trivial syntax error here.

Comment: `if (increasing)` **`{} /*!!!*/`** `if(...)`

Comment: "There are both increase and increasing – typo? Use consistent variable names" Yes thx for the info, in the last code i haveclean the bug. But it also does not work. I will explain again what i mean:

I get numbers like this: 10,13,14,23(peakmax), 7,5,2,1(peakmin),2,4,6,(peakmax)3,1(peakmin),3,4..

Now i want to safe peak max 1 until peak max 2, and also peak min 1 until peak min 2 etc pp...

Comment: frankly it looks like you started to write code too early. Once you have a clear definition of what is the minimum you want to store, ie what exactly do you call a "peak", then it doesnt matter if you have the sensor values written on a sheet of paper or if you sit in front of a scope or if you write code. It will always be just a realization of your definition of what makes a peak a peak that you need to apply.

Comment: in other words, the problem is not code or programming, but that you are missing a formal definition of what a peak is or what min and max you need to store. Once you got that, writing the code will be the simple part

Comment: "in other words, the problem is not code or programming, but that you are missing a formal definition of what a peak is " ... exakt! :)

Comment: Get used to proper code formatting (at best use an auto-formatter) – this would help tremendously to discover structural problems of your code like the surplus pair of braces (see my previous comment). The algorithm itself seems to be correct, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G9dG1W481) (assuming waves without jittering like a pure sinus wave), but on implementing it you lost yourself in the wild formatting jungle of your code...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks very much! I will implement the code again. But I still need the min and max values as separate variables. How would you solve that? Possibly an if loop, if peak max and peak min 0 R = first value and if peak max or peak max =! 0 r = the second value, if the second value > first value second value == peak max else second value == peak min and now?

Comment: By using two variables – note that you if you newly determine a minimum or maximum you need to reset the respective counterpart appropriately, e.g. like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TxdG7PcE8).

Comment: Thanks Aconcagua you help me a lot!!